# Standard graph - Determining sizes of restriction fragments

Tags: dna, restriction-enzymes

[image: This is our task]

I have marked out Lane M and gotten a roughly straight line, it then says that I am supposed to estimate the length of lane H and R. I am not sure what they are asking. I am still supposed to measure the distance migrated and then just plot it next to lane M on the graph or am I using lane M in order to actually plot the rest of the lanes, is it that by having both the length and fragment size of lane M, that I should be able to look at the fragment size and by using lane M be able to tell how far the DNA has migrated?

Comment: could you rotate the picture 90 degrees counterclockwise?

Comment: **PLEASE DO NOT POST TEXT AS IMAGES**. Copy and paste the text into your question. Images are not searchable, and can not be interpreted by screen readers for those with visual impairments. Use the [edit] link to modify your question. See [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1426065) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

The lane marked 'M' contains molecular weight markers of known sizes (in this case we are not using the actual MW of each double-stranded DNA fragment, instead we are using the length of each dsDNA fragment, measured in either base pairs (bp) of kilobases (kb)).

1. Plot the size of the MW standards on the log axis of the semi-log paper, and plot the distance that each fragment migrated through the gel on the other axis (the linear axis). Depending on the electrophoresis conditions you should be able to connect these points in a smooth line with a negative slope. At higher MW the line's slope will curve and get steeper.
2. Measure the distance that each band in lane 'H' migrated through the gel. Take those distances, and see where the fall on your standard curve that you plotted at Step. 1. You should be able to place the distance on the x-axis and read off the corresponding dsDNA fragment size on the Y-axis.
3. Repeat Step 2 using the distances that you measured for the fragments in lane R to find out the approximate sizes of those dsDNA fragments as well.